# Modify column value in CSV File in task SSIS(Dtsx)

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I have this SSIS task, I read the contents of a CSV file and then I insert into a table
[image]

In one of the columns I should perform a trim in the values ​​before inserting them in the table, how can I modify the csv before the insert?

Comment: Are you sure that you use MySQL? maybe you use SQL Server aka MS SQL ?

Comment: Maybe insert first then perform an UPDATE on the table after ?

Comment: Sorry, you are right I clicked the first thing that came out, it was MS Sql

Comment: @blabla_bingo no because the column has 16 characters, and the cell starting with a space truncates the last character

Comment: In SSIS, you can use `Derived Column` to change information. In this component, there is a `trim` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Derived Column transformation in the data flow between the Flat File Source and the ADO/ODBC/OLE Destination there.

If you want to trim, then you need to apply both a left and a right trim operation. I favor creating new columns versus renaming existing as I find it's easier to debug.

Assuming I have an inbound column named `Col1`, I would define a new column called `Col1_Trimmed` And remember that SSIS column names are case sensitive

```
LTRIM(RTRIM([Col1]]
```

Caveats about what is whitespace in the [documentation for LTRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/ltrim-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver16)